# Penalty to withdraw from a new Roth IRA for first time home buyers?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, first-time-home-buyer

My wife & I are 28 and plan on purchasing our first home in the next 1-3 years.  Right now our assets are in two places:

- 403-b that I will not touch for the next 30+ years
- FDIC-insured savings account earning 1% interest

I have the option to start a Roth IRA account under [a fund that offers a guaranteed 3% return](http://www.tiaa-cref.org/public/performance/retirement/profiles/4001.html).  My understanding of Roth IRAs is [limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth_ira), but I understand that first time home buyers can withdraw $10,000 ($20,000 joint) to purchase a new home.  However, are there any restrictions to taking this money out?  It's unclear to me if a [5-year "seasoning" period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth_ira#Distributions) applies to first time homebuyers (ie. would we incur a 10% penalty for withdrawing up to $10,000 ($20,000 joint) on a Roth IRA that is less than 5 years old?)

Thanks for [Alex B](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/815/alex-b) for suggesting that I migrate this question [from here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/looking-to-buy-a-house-in-1-2-years-does-starting-a-roth-ira-now-make-sense).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Roth IRAs divide your withdrawal into 3 categories: Contributions, Conversions, and Earnings.

This is significant, because each have different tax consequences and the order of withdrawal is dictated by tax law.

- Contributions - First to be withdrawn.  This is the money you invested and has already had taxes paid on it.  No taxes will need to be paid on it.
- Conversions - Second to be withdrawn.  This is money converted from a traditional IRA and does sound like it applies in your question.
- Earnings - Last to be withdrawn.  This is investment gain made from contributions and conversions.

You **can** withdraw your **contributions** in less than 5 years for any reason (home buyer or not).

You **cannot** withdraw your **conversions** or **earnings** without waiting 5 years unless you pay the 10% penalty.  The home buyer exemption is only after the 5 years are met.

Further detail: [home purchase exemption](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/110415/can-you-use-your-ira-buy-house.asp), [withdraw contributions](https://www.schwab.com/ira/roth-ira/withdrawal-rules#:%7E:text=You%20can%20withdraw%20contributions%20you,had%20less%20than%20five%20years.), [early withdrawal penalties](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/082515/how-do-you-calculate-penalties-ira-or-roth-ira-early-withdrawal.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You may withdraw your **contributions** to a Roth IRA at any time for any reason without penalty.

Any **gains** you withdraw may be subject to tax or penalties though, but there is a $10,000 exclusion (from the 10% penalty, not the taxes) for a first time home purchase.

Comment: Good information, but doesn't answer the question about the seasoning period.