# Can I withdraw Roth 401k contributions penalty-free before age 59.5?

Tags: roth-ira, contribution, roth-401k

I know that with a Roth IRA, contributions can be withdrawn penalty-free at any time. If I rollover a Roth 401k into a Roth IRA, can I do the same with the contributions made to the Roth 401k?

I've [read](http://www.mymoneyblog.com/can-i-really-withdraw-my-roth-ira-contributions-at-any-time-without-tax-or-penalty.html) that the entire Roth 401k->Roth IRA rollover counts for penalty-free/tax-free early withdrawal, but that sounds too good to be true.

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/penalty-to-withdraw-from-a-new-roth-ira-for-first-time-home-buyers

Answer (score 7):

I spent some time searching, and couldn't find the answer written explicitly in IRS regulations.

What I did find was this [chart](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/roth_differences.pdf) from the irs showing that nonqualified distributions from a Roth 401k are pro-rated between contributions and earnings.

It is well documented that you can't withdraw any money early or tax free (even contributions) from a Roth 401k ("Designated Roth Account" in IRS parlance) that has made any money. [source](http://www.irs.gov/retirement/article/0,,id=152956,00.html)

You can do a direct rollover from a "Designated Roth Account" to a Roth IRA and the basis  describing contributions vs. earnings is preserved. [source](http://www.irs.gov/retirement/article/0,,id=152956,00.html#27)

And there is plenty of evidence showing you can withdraw contributions from a Roth IRA without penalty. [source](http://www.fool.com/money/allaboutiras/allaboutiras07.htm)

All that being said, I can't find anything from the IRS that says this is a legitimate strategy.

Comment: Thanks, that's along the lines of what I've been seeing when I look into it, too.