# Savings account vs Roth 401k

Tags: united-states, savings, roth-401k, savings-account

Is there any reason to have a savings account if you have a Roth 401(k), which allows early withdrawal  of principal? If pooled together, couldn't you get the liquidity of a savings account and, if you don't end up needing the money until retirement, the tax free growth of the Roth?

I realize there are some potential psychological benefits of having money that you don't touch until retirement, but is there any other benefits to keeping them separate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that withdraws from the retirement account are possible: there is no way to put the money back beyond the annual maximums.

Assume this scenario:

- have 10K in contributions and 5K in earnings.
- Get hit with big bill because of storm damage to your house.
- Have to pay the repair company, so pull the 10K from the retirement fund.
- Many months later the insurance company finally agrees to pay you back, now you have a 10K check and no way to put the money back into the retirement account.
- Time to open a savings account.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this document from Morgan Stanley](http://www.morganstanleyfa.com/public/projectfiles/627909bb-5718-4c45-b372-8f66239bd7bc.pdf), you can't withdraw contributions penalty-free from a Roth 401k (unlike a Roth IRA, where you can).

There are a few benefits to a savings account:

1. Assuming your Roth is invested in stocks and/or bonds, it can lose value.  If the stock market goes down at the time when you need to draw on your "savings", you can wind up taking a big bite out of your retirement.  For an emergency fund, a savings account is safer as it cannot lose (nominal) value.
2. A savings account is typically FDIC insured, so you can recover your money (up to a limit) even if the bank fails.  Although this is unlikely, it's still nice to know that protection is there
3. It is possible that tax treatment of Roth IRAs/401ks may change in the future.  If you put all your savings eggs in the Roth basket and then the law changes so that a penalty is applied, you are blocked from retrieving your "savings" penalty free.  (It is theoretically possible that a law could also be passed to impose penalties on withdrawals from savings accounts, but this is obviously a more remote possibility.)

Comment: You can't withdraw early from a Roth 401(k) (as far as I know) only Roth IRA.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Interesting, I was looking that up.  I can't find a clear statement from the IRS about it, though.  Do you know of one?

Comment: no, but there was a discussion of this on a LinkedIn group I follow. The lack of this option was cited as a big downside in the writer's opinion.

Comment: Looks like you're right about no early withdrawl from Roth 401(k): http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/can-i-withdraw-roth-401k-contributions-penalty-free-before-age-59-5

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going to use a Roth IRA for other purposes (like retirement), then go ahead.

- Money contributed to either a savings account or a Roth IRA will have been taxed at three marginal tax rate when your earned the money.
- Savings will grow at an interest rate of 1.0% at best, less 25% (or whatever your marginal tax rate is). In a Roth IRA, you are penalized if you withdraw more than the principal. Any earnings in a Roth IRA on the investment will not be accessible without penalty until age 59.5. The Roth IRA can lose value if the securities are not risk-free. You can also open a Roth IRA that uses certificate of deposits to grow in value. This is essentially a tax-free savings account with a $5500/year contribution limit and a withdrawal limit with earnings that are accessible at retirement.

Unless you save enough to max out your 401k contributions ($17,500) using your Roth IRA ($5500) as a tax-free savings account or personal investing account seems like a good idea.

Comment: "Roth IRAs will grow by 0% if you plan to take an early withdrawal of your contributions (no earnings)". There is earnings, you just can't access them tax free until retirement.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the feedback. I reworded it to make it clearer.